# How to map lines of a 3d matrix

Tags: matlab, function, mapping

I want to pass all the lines (in a particular dimension) of a 3d matrix through a function that accepts arrays. I know I can do this with two for loops, but that's not the idea.

I tried to use arrayfun but I could not make it work.

```
linemean=@(x) mean(x)  %it's just an example of fucntion
m=rand(3,3,3)
```

so that way I would have a 3x3 matrix at the end, whose elements corresponds to linemean applied to each m(i, j , :) line. Any help would be great. Thank you.

Comment: “I can do this with two for loops, but that's not the idea.” Why not? What is wrong with that? Did you implement it with loops and noticed it was a bottleneck? If not, there is no reason for this question. MATLAB hasn’t been slow with loops in 15 years...

Comment: It's not just because I wanted to know if there is something better. But that's the way I'm doing it rigth now.

Comment: In that case I recommend that you post your loop code, and ask for something faster/shorter/whatever bothers you. Read [mre] before preparing your code to post it here.

Comment: I posted a simple solution, without using `arrayfun`.

Comment: @GabrielMachado If your problem was solved by one of the answers, consider accepting one of them. (or commenting where you are stuck or how you solved it yourself so that others landing on this question are informed too)

Answer (score 1):

Specifically for the `mean` function:

```
A = rand(3,3,3);
result = mean(A,3);
```

For an arbitrary function:

```
A = rand(3,3,3);
func = @(x) mean(x);
C = mat2cell(A,ones(1,size(A,1)),ones(1,size(A,2)),size(A,3));
result = cellfun(func,C);
```

*Note 1:* 
[`mat2cell`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html)
dissects the matrix into separate smaller matrices storing them in a cell array. The way I call it above, it dissects the matrix along the 1st and 2nd dimension, creating a (3x3) cell array containing a (1x1x3) matrix array in each cell.

*Note 2:*
[`mean`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mean.html)
computes the mean on the first non-singleton dimension, therefore in each cell with dimensions (1x1x3) along the 3rd dimension. If your arbitrary func works differently, eg. sums strictly along the 1st dimension, you can change your arbitrary function to something like `func = @(x) arbitrFunc(squeeze(x))`. [`squeeze`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/squeeze.html) will remove the singleton dimensions turning each cell into a (3x1) matrix.

Comment: As a performance comment on the above answer: While it is a valid/fancy way to do it, I doubt it would be faster (most probably slower due to the array dissecting etc) than traditional for-loops as correctly pointed out by @Cris in an OP comment.

Comment: I think the result supposed to be 3x3 matrix. Your result is 3x1.

Answer (score 0):

In case you just want to vectorize the computations, you can do it as follows:

Reshape `m` to `3` by `size(m,1)*size(m,2)` (each column is the "line" in the 3'ed dimension).
Perform the computation on each of the columns, and reshape to 2D matrix:

```
M = reshape(permute(m, [3, 1, 2]), [size(m,3), size(m,1)*size(m,2), 1]);
m_means = reshape(mean(M, 1), [size(m,1), size(m,2)]);
```

---

In case you must use `arrayfun`, I have a solution, but it's a little awkward:

Solution assumes `m` is a constant (not a parameter to `arrayfun`).

```
% %Prepare 3x4x3 natrix for testing
m = cat(3, [1 2 3 4; 5, 6, 7, 8; 9, 10, 11, 12], [21 22 23 24; 25, 26, 27, 28; 29, 30, 31, 32], [41 42 43 44; 45, 46, 47, 48; 49, 40, 41, 42]);

%For testing:
%linemean=@(x) disp(num2str(m(floor(x/size(m,2))+1, mod(x, size(m,1))+1, :)));

%Use floor and mod for computing indices (ind2sub did't work)
linemean = @(x) mean(m(mod(x, size(m,1))+1, floor(x/size(m,1))+1, :));

%Apply arrayfun on array of indices 0:11
m_means = arrayfun(linemean, 0:size(m,1)*size(m,2)-1);

%Reshape to size of m
m_means = reshape(m_means, size(m,1), size(m,2))
```

Result:

`m_means =`

`21.0000   22.0000   23.0000   24.0000`
`25.0000   26.0000   27.0000   28.0000`
`29.0000   26.6667   27.6667   28.6667`